# Is testflightapp.com being supporred by Apple?

Tags: ios, testflight

Recently, we are planning  use an on the air distribution method to distribute our iOS app to different people. I know what I am asking is silly. But I just got a confusion.

"We know that recently Apple released their own TestFlight application which is nicely integrated with iTunes connect to help the developers. But there is also the testflightapp.com which existed long before the new TestFlight. And later Apple acquired the Burstly, the owner of testflightapp.com.

The point is that 'are both the TestFlight versions are different from each other?' And are both of them supported by Apple?"

Comment: this might get closed as a "primarily opinion based question", but I have a feeling Apple is eventually going to close and/or merge the testflightapp.com service into developer.apple.com.  If I were pushing a new app out for testing, use what's available in Xcode 6 and via apple.com.

Comment: Ohh :-( but any idea where should i ask these kinds of questions? Anyways thanks for your clarification and answer.

Comment: Only Apple knows what they are going to do with testflightapp.com and what the timetable is, and they're not going to tell it to peons like me or you. We just have to make guesses (and form opinions) as to what might be next.

Comment: That's really true!! But my question was "Is testflightapp.com being supported by Apple currently?"